# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2

Tags: android

The error message says:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2

and

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2

How do I resolove this?

Comment: Have you included `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` or `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` in your app level build.gradle file dependencies?

Comment: Share your app level build.gradle file code

Comment: Updated formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any dependencies you can follow with these steps  in Android Studio itself.

Step:1 
[image]

Step:2
[image]

Step:3
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your build. Gradle file and it should work fine

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
```

Comment: Make sure your build tools version matches the recycler view version.

Comment: If still the problem persist, please share your build. Gradle file